# PHP MySQL: Better Way to Update tag system

Tags: php, mysql

I insert multiple tags in MySql database like this :

```
| id | tagname | articleid | 
----------------------------
| 1  |   PHP   |    120    |
----------------------------
| 2  | Linux   |    120    |
----------------------------
| 3  | Apache  |    120    |
```

Now, in edit page i need to edit tags(add new tags - remove tags Or insert/update existing tags).

**My Method:**(in action)

**First**: I delete all `tags` with `articleid`

**Second**: Insert existing or New/edit `tags`.

My Method Is true and optimized?!

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are we talking millions of tags edited at once, or 3-4 tags edited at once? Are you sure you're optimizing the most important/frequent use case for tags?

Comment: I have Maximum 5 tags for each article.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a UNIQUE index that only allows each tag to appear once per article. Once you've done that, you can use a single DELETE and a single INSERT IGNORE to keep the tags that already exist and add the new ones; note that you only need to list the tags as they are after update;

```
-- Done a single time for the table. Disallows duplicates

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tag_article_uq ON mytable(tagname, articleid);

-- Items have been updated/added to add Python/Nginx and remove Apache

-- Delete all tags that aren't listed for articleid 120    

DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE articleid=120 AND tagname NOT IN ('PHP', 'Linux', 'Python', 'Nginx');

-- Add the tags that don't already exist for articleid 120.

INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable (tagname, articleid) VALUES
('PHP', 120), ('Linux', 120), ('Python', 120), ('Nginx', 120);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a515/1).